# Radon-Nikodym for thress measures.

Tags: radon-nikodym

Let $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ and $\nu$ be two finite measures on the measurable space $(\Omega, \mathcal{S})$ such that $\nu \ll \mu_i$, $i = 1, 2$, and $f_i = \frac{d\nu}{d\mu_i}$. Show that then $\nu \ll \mu_1 + \mu_2$ and
$$
\frac{d\nu}{d(\mu_1 + \mu_2)} = \frac{f_1 \cdot f_2}{f_1 + f_2}
$$

I have managed to prove the first part of it, but i have some question for the second part. Just by writing the definition of the f i and transforming the eqution i get to.
$$
\frac{d\nu}{d(\mu_1) + d(\mu_2)}
$$
is this equal to the statment above?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\int_E (\frac 1 {f_1}+\frac  1{f_2}) d\nu=\int_E \frac 1 {f_1} f_1d\mu_1+\int_E \frac 1 {f_1} f_1d\mu_2=\mu_1(E)+\mu_2(E)$ and this implies $\frac {d\nu}{d(\mu_1+\mu_2)}=\frac 1 {\frac 1 {f_1}+\frac  1{f_2}}=\frac {f_1f_2}{f_1+f_2}$.

Comment: Thank you. I understand your answer but i have one question. What is the reason you wrote $\int_E (\frac 1 {f_1}+\frac  1{f_2}) d\nu $ .  I dont know how oyu got there

Comment: All I did was to bring RHS down to LHS and move $\mu_1+\mu_2$ to RHS. Simple algebraic manipulation.  @vwhg1050

Comment: but why$\mu_1(E)+\mu_2(E)$ and not $d(\mu_1(E)+\mu_2(E))$

Comment: $\int_E d(\mu_1+\mu_2)$  is nothing but $\mu_1(E)+\mu_2 (E)$.

Comment: thank you, i got it now